# Rodrigues rotation formula

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to solve for theta in Rodrigues' formula. I have the rotation axis, the vector to be rotated, and one dimension of the vector after rotation. I end up with a equation of this format:

$$0 = A\cos\theta + B\sin\theta + C$$

where $A$, $B$, and $C$ are known.

What approach can I take to solve for $\theta$? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to know the angle? You likely have enough information to construct an appropriate rotation matrix some other way.

Comment: If you want to solve it, may be the tangent half-angle substitution could help.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are in general going to be two solutions, so you’ll need more information or assumptions to choose between them.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry/Solving_Trigonometric_Equations#a_sin(x)+b_cos(x)_=_c

Comment: Thanks all. I solved it another way. I found the point on the rotation axis, which together with the point to be rotated, forms a perpendicular line to the rotation axis. After rotation, the line formed by the two points should still be perpendicular to the rotation axis, and the distance should remain the same. I just solved for that, with the knowledge of one of the coordinates of the rotated point.

Not as elegant, but works...

Comment: @user672621 That should have left you with two possible solutions. You must be making some other assumptions about this rotation that you’ve not stated in your question.

Comment: Yes it does. When I take the root, excel automatically defines it as a positive number. I didn't state further assumptions/restrictions in the question because it's ok for the time being. As long as I can solve for the two solutions, I'll know which is the answer I need. It is a physical system and I just don't want to go through paragraphs explaining the system.